# Microsoft Test Manager: I have not found Do Exploratory Testing tab in Test Manager 2012

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 ultimate with Microsoft Test Manager, reviewing the bibliography this version allow to make Exploratory Test, but in my Microsoft Test Manager, in the Test Tab i can´t see Do Exploratory Testing tab, i read the help from this version and i realize this tab is included by default, well i do not know if it is necessary configure something in Microsoft Test Manager, in Team Foundation Server or Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are using MTM 2012 with TFS 2010, see [MTM 2012 Compatibility with TFS 2010](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4e1b02b-1888-49a4-851e-1b0688a1c196/mtm-2012-compatibility-with-tfs-2010?forum=vsmantest)
So you will need at least TFS 2012.

If you can't upgrade to TFS 2012 for any reason, check this article about [using exploratory bugs](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/eranruso/2010/12/07/visual-studio-test-manager-2010-exploratory-testing/).
It could help you in the time you are waiting for TFS upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

reinstall visual studio,as much i know there is no special configuration needed to be done.